# concatenate two data frames with different length under block_wise index in one frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I need to concatenate two kind of date frame with different length:

The one data frame is like below with index but block_wise:
[image]

There is total three block_wise index [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], the total length is 20.

The second frame has only one column:
[image]
This column represent a enum-like variable could be with duplication,can be int or string. but the length of this column/frame is strictly equal to the block level of index in frame one. So three block index in one frame, the length of two is 3.

What i want is below concatenated table:
[image]

What is the best way to do it in Pandas? the block level & factor level could be far more than 3.

Comment: The second frame with enum-like variable, can be have duplication, but the index under certain block is one by one correspond with the second frame's data by order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` of new column `D` created by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of `boolean mask`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(1,21)}, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]+[0,1,2,3,4]+[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
df['B'] = 'b_' + df.A.astype('str')
df['C'] = 'c_' + df.A.astype('str')
df['A'] = 'a_' + df.A.astype('str')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'D':['X','Y','Z']})

df['D'] = (df.index == 0).cumsum() - 1

d = df1['D'].to_dict()
print (d)
{0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z'}
df.D = df.D.map(d)
print (df)
      A     B     C  D
0   a_1   b_1   c_1  X
1   a_2   b_2   c_2  X
2   a_3   b_3   c_3  X
3   a_4   b_4   c_4  X
4   a_5   b_5   c_5  X
5   a_6   b_6   c_6  X
6   a_7   b_7   c_7  X
7   a_8   b_8   c_8  X
0   a_9   b_9   c_9  Y
1  a_10  b_10  c_10  Y
2  a_11  b_11  c_11  Y
3  a_12  b_12  c_12  Y
4  a_13  b_13  c_13  Y
0  a_14  b_14  c_14  Z
1  a_15  b_15  c_15  Z
2  a_16  b_16  c_16  Z
3  a_17  b_17  c_17  Z
4  a_18  b_18  c_18  Z
5  a_19  b_19  c_19  Z
6  a_20  b_20  c_20  Z
```

Comment: @ChrinideWu - some problem?

Comment: @jezrael No problem, my boy just touch my computer@_@,Thanks  a lot again

Comment: :D It is nice ;)